# How to draw attention to a closed question that has been edited so it can be re-opened?

Tags: support, closed-questions

How to draw attention to a [closed question](https://serverfault.com/questions/445389/how-to-monitor-multiple-sites-using-one-copy-of-apc-php) that has been edited and is up for a review and possible re-opening?

This information is not in the [FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq#close). I don't want to be lazy and simply create another (updated) question. **What should I do so that people with re-opening powers check out the new and improved question?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should flag it so that a moderator can review it.

Comment: or if you're eligible to do so cast a reopen vote on it (which will put it into http://serverfault.com/review/reopen

Comment: Or just flag it... This happens so infrequently that flagging is probably the best option.